# Error parsing XML: not well-formed - android application

Tags: android

Hi I cant see what I am doing wrong here, maybe spelling error or something.
I have looked but cant see anything wrong.

Hi I cant see what I am doing wrong here, maybe spelling error or something.
I have looked but cant see anything wrong.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.facebooklogin.FacebookLogin" 
android:background="@drawable/faceb_background" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/img_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/faceb_login" />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/eamil_login"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img_login"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/password_login"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eamil_login"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password_login"
    android:text="@string/login_btn_txt" >
</Button>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login_btn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="@string/forgot_password_txt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="@string/register_txt" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've copied and paste your xml and replaced the `drawable` and `string` references with another ones and nothing appears to be wrong in your xml perhaps the issue relies  elsewhere in another xml file, or in the resource references you use in this xml such as `@drawable/faceb_login`

Comment: You might want to add the xml heading; `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`